# How can I install a nightly build?

Tags: installation, cinnamon, mint

I would like to install the [nightly build of Cinnamon desktop](https://launchpad.net/~gwendal-lebihan-dev/+archive/cinnamon-nightly). Currently I am using the stable version (1.4 as of 16.9.2012).

I added the ppa for nightly build. Do I need to remove the stable cinnamon first or can I just do *apt-get install cinnamon*?

Comment: It seems that the linked ppa is no longer being actively maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have added the new PPA then you've to remove old PPA of Cinnamon.

one more point is that To  avoid configurations conflicts you should have to remove the old installed Cinnamon  completely that too with purge .

then you can go for installation .